# SQL Query conversion of the Month

Tags: sql, sql-server

Query below returns the date as the month in lower case, I need the month in upper case any help would be much appreciated. Current 08 Aug 2012 and I need 08 AUG 2012.

```
Select 
    RTrim(Right(MTRL.MTRL_NBR, 9)) As MTRL_NBR, 
    RTrim(PROD_ORDR.PROD_ORDR_NBR) As ORDER_NBR, 
    RTrim(PROD_ORDR.BTCH_NBR) As BATCH_NBR, 
    RTrim(PROD_ORDR.RVSN_LVL) As REV_LVL, 
    Convert(VARCHAR(11),PROD_ORDR.ACT_RLSE_DT,106) As RELEASE_DATE 
From 
    MPM.DBO.PROD_ORDR 
Inner Join MPM.DBO.MTRL 
    On PROD_ORDR.MTRL_OID = MTRL.OID 
Where PROD_ORDR.PROD_ORDR_NBR = 000104007817
```

Comment: [`UPPER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180055.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
Select  
    RTrim(Right(MTRL.MTRL_NBR, 9)) As MTRL_NBR,  
    RTrim(PROD_ORDR.PROD_ORDR_NBR) As ORDER_NBR,  
    RTrim(PROD_ORDR.BTCH_NBR) As BATCH_NBR,  
    RTrim(PROD_ORDR.RVSN_LVL) As REV_LVL,  
    UPPER(Convert(VARCHAR(11),PROD_ORDR.ACT_RLSE_DT,106)) As RELEASE_DATE  
From  
    MPM.DBO.PROD_ORDR  
Inner Join MPM.DBO.MTRL  
    On PROD_ORDR.MTRL_OID = MTRL.OID  
Where PROD_ORDR.PROD_ORDR_NBR = 000104007817
```

Answer (score 1):

If You using sql server than you can use Upper() function

```
Select RTrim(Right(MTRL.MTRL_NBR, 9)) As MTRL_NBR, 
        RTrim(PROD_ORDR.PROD_ORDR_NBR) As ORDER_NBR, 
        RTrim(PROD_ORDR.BTCH_NBR) As BATCH_NBR, RTrim(PROD_ORDR.RVSN_LVL) As REV_LVL, 
        Upper(Convert(VARCHAR(11),PROD_ORDR.ACT_RLSE_DT,106)) As RELEASE_DATE From MPM.DBO.PROD_ORDR Inner Join MPM.DBO.MTRL On PROD_ORDR.MTRL_OID = MTRL.OID Where PROD_ORDR.PROD_ORDR_NBR = 000104007817
```

Answer (score 0):

USE `UPPER` function to do it for you.

```
SELECT  RTrim(Right(MTRL.MTRL_NBR, 9)) As MTRL_NBR,  
        RTrim(PROD_ORDR.PROD_ORDR_NBR) As ORDER_NBR,  
        RTrim(PROD_ORDR.BTCH_NBR) As BATCH_NBR,  
        RTrim(PROD_ORDR.RVSN_LVL) As REV_LVL,  
        UPPER(Convert(VARCHAR(11),PROD_ORDR.ACT_RLSE_DT,106)) As RELEASE_DATE  
FROM    MPM.DBO.PROD_ORDR  
           INNER JOIN MPM.DBO.MTRL  
              ON PROD_ORDR.MTRL_OID = MTRL.OID  
WHERE   PROD_ORDR.PROD_ORDR_NBR = 000104007817
```